# py2app cannot exclude module properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, pyqt5, py2app

I am trying to use the py2app build an app bundle with PyQt5 and exclude unnecessary modole, however, I still get the entire PyQt5 package in my app which is over 200MB

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['browser.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True, 'includes': ['PyQt5.QtCore', 'PyQt5.QtGui', 'PyQt5.QtWidgets'],
        'excludes': ['PyQt5.QtDesigner', 'PyQt5.QtNetwork', 'PyQt5.QtOpenGL', 'PyQt5.QtScript', 'PyQt5.QtSql', 'PyQt5.QtTest','PyQt5.QtXml', 'PyQt5.QtHelp','QtHelp','QtSerialPort','QtHelp.so','PyQt5.QtHelp.so']}

setup(
app=APP,
data_files=DATA_FILES,
options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
setup_requires=['py2app'],
```

)

and here is browser.py

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setWindowTitle('My Browser')

        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icons/penguin.png'))
        self.show()


        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        url = 'https://www.google.com/'

        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl(url))

        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()

window.show()

app.exec_()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Update:

My current way is just cut the PyQt5 and left necessary package only. replace the PyQt with the cut one.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with my PyQt5 projects.

The solution I use is to delete files after py2app has built the app.
In my case that saves around 100MiB.

You can see the code I use in here:

https://github.com/barry-scott/scm-workbench/blob/master/Kit/macOS/build-app.sh

The basic idea is to only include the listed PyQt5 modules.
I manually set the list of modules that are used.